# Downloading from android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-download-manager

i have a web view in android and want to download files that are session based, for example the url for all files is http://123.com/files.aspx  and the session is session["adr"]="address of file", so the problem is how can i download these kind of files from android web view?

the code for downloading is :

```
WebView mWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.Mainwbv);
    mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The for the downloading is correct. What is your problem ?

Comment: Hi , the problem is , that it just opening a browser(chrome) with link  http://123.com/files.aspx and no session , there for it cant download the file

Comment: url you gave is not working. However, you need to get the cookie, sync it and set it before sending it to browser.